# How to get "xelatex.ini" in order to make a xelatex format?

Tags: xetex, fmtutil

I've retrieved xetex from TUG's 2013 TeX Collection disk for experimental use in private space, and I want to use xelatex.  In trying to run xelatex on a tex file, some part of it begins to generate a xelatex format but fails for lack of
"xelatex.ini".  Where do I find that?  It's not at CTAN.  Is it something I should generate?  If so, how?

Comment: Did your try a 'live' TeX Live or MiKTeX system (_e.g._ `kpsewhich xelatex.ini`). These `.ini` files are in `tex/latex/latexconfig`, usually. (Indeed, the team is currently looking at trying to pull a lot of this stuff back into the format or a related file.)

Comment: Thanks, Joseph.  That put me on the right track: search with tlmgr to identify the packages I needed from the disk.  All to have a new enough xelatex to work with current xunicode and unicode-math.    -- Bill